# Writing to json file Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am making an app where I need to store data (json format) in a file on the physical device.

The problem I am having is that by placing files in the assets folder they become read only, which is half of the battle, I can read them but then where do I place the files to make them writable?

When I move them to the specialFolder.Personal I am met with null reference exceptions and when I move them anywhere else I am met with accessDenied exceptions.

Any help is appreciated (I am still fairly new to Xamarin but I do have good experience in C#).

Thanks in advance.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to read all data from player data json file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Player> GetAllPlayerData()
    {
        return ReadFile(playerdata);
    }

    ^^ This method is returning null.

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to read JSON data from a specified file path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<Player> ReadFile(string path)
    {
        if (!(File.Exists(path)))
        {
            File.Create(path).Dispose();
        }

        List<Player> data = new List<Player>();

        string jsondata = File.ReadAllText(path);         
        data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(jsondata);

        return data;
    }

    ^^ This method reads in the data.

    private string playerdata = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "playerdata.json");

    private string teamdata = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "team.json");

    ^^ These are the file paths used to read in the data.

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to write JSON data to a specified file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private void WriteFile(string path, List<Player> data)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }

    ^^ Here is the method which rights to files.
```

Comment: You need to figure out why you're getting exceptions when writing to SpecialFolders.Personal.   Please post the relevant portions of your code

Comment: @Jason I have now provided some code snippets for you.

Comment: `File.Create(path).Dispose();` So you create an empty file? that would return a null from DeserializeObject.  Where/When are you copying the file(s) from the native Assets?

Comment: @SushiHangover the files need to be empty to start with, it is an app where a player will enter the names of their teammates. No initial values are shipped with the app. Any ideas?

Comment: @JamesTheHunt Where are you writing to the file(s)?

Comment: @SushiHangover just added that method to the code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

try this - you don't need to explicitly create the file, File.WriteAllText() should do that for you

```
private List<Player> ReadFile(string path)
{
    List<Player> data = new List<Player>();

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
      string jsondata = File.ReadAllText(path);         
      data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(jsondata);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So... I just fixed it through some more debugging. The issue was that when I created the blank file, it did not have the []'s needed for json. so it was returning null.

The way I fixed it was by adding the one player the app is designed for so it had an initial JSON object to deserialize or serialize.

Thanks all for your help!